# 3d qqplots in R

Tags: r, quantile

Does anyone know how to plot 3d Q-Q plots for quantile regression using mtcars data? Something like the following plot. I can use plotly to visualize the regression coefficients but I have never used 3d qq plots.
[image]

Comment: Can you give a link that explains more about how these plots are derived? `plot3D::persp3D` will be useful once you have got the values you want to display ...

Comment: It is from a published paper: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1354816619859695

Comment: Found a good video that partly answered my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPDr-BbRfK0&t=1303s&ab_channel=R_PyDataScience